# Can Excel Office Open XML do a filtered list of data validations?

Tags: excel, openxml

We have a excel xml spreadsheet that gets created from our software using office open xml 2003:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_format

It has one sheet that uses datavalidations to limit entry based on another sheet.

**Sheet 1**

```
Column 1     Column 2
Category     Selected Value
---------------------
Category1    Selected Value from drop list (data validation from column 2 sheet 2)
Category2    Selected Value from drop list (data validation from column 2 sheet 2)
```

**Sheet 2**

```
Column 1     Column 2
Category     Value
---------------------
Category1    A
Category1    B
Category2    A
Category2    Z
```

The user is allowed to add Categories and selected values to sheet 1, so presently column2 of sheet 1 all has the same data validation (column 2 of sheet 2) so if values are added they show up in the drop list.

Sheet 2 column 2 is used for the validation list for column 2 on sheet1 but this means the user can select the wrong value for a category since it shows the valid entries for ALL categories not just the right ones for that particular category.

While a static validation list per row/cell (is supported) on sheet 1 column 2 per cell wouldn't work since the user could add new entries for the category and then they wouldn't be able to select the right values. (xml format also doesn't seem to save macro's/vba code so that seems to limit things).

Is there are way to make this work with Excel Office Open XML 2003 format so the user would only see appropriate values for the category in the data validation drop list in sheet 1 column 2 for each category? (while still allowing the user to add new categories or category values on the two sheets?)

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use named ranges with range definition by formula? Is the data in sheet2 in sorted order by category, value by default?

Comment: I don't know if open xml supports that.  Even if it does if it's a static range it would require re-organizing the spreadsheet.  Formula's seem to be allowed though but I don't know if a formula can be used as a range.  If it could then would need a formula that could select just the values for a specific category.  Data in sheet 2 is not necessarily in sorted order for categories or values since the user can enter them in theory in any order.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Microsoft Open XML. I've asked because there is a solution with native Excel to achieve this. But it needs a named range which refers to the result of a matrix formula and it requires the data in that named range in sorted order.